# Using Backbone.js View remove() method with jQuery's fadeOut()

Tags: jquery, backbone.js, coffeescript

I believe that my title almost explains what I wish to achieve, I have a Backbone View with an event that removes itself via [view.remove()](http://backbonejs.org/#View-remove)

More precisely:

```
class Project.Views.MemberView extends Backbone.View
  template: JST['members/member_view']

  events:
    'click .destroy-member': 'removeMember'

  initialize: ->
    _.bindAll(this, "render")

  render: ->
    $(@el).html(@template(member: @model))
    this

  removeMember: ->
    @model.destroy
      data:
        collective_id: gon.collective.id
      contentType: 'application/json'
      success: =>
        @remove() #view.remove() called here
```

This call to **view.remove()** works well and as expected, however it removes the element (View) from the DOM instantly, and I don't think that's very good User experience.

What I need to know is, If there's a way to *wrap* or *chain* this call to view.remove() with a [Jquery fadeOut()](http://api.jquery.com/fadeOut/). That'll improve the user experience quite a bit in my opinion.

Is this posible?

Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why don't you just call the fadeOut before the remove? I'm not familiar with coffeescript, but before you call the model destroy, just do something like:

```
removeMember: ->
    // whatever el you want to remove, just fade it out. from your code maybe its $(@el) ?:
    @model.destroy
      data:
        collective_id: gon.collective.id
      contentType: 'application/json'
      success: =>
        $(@el).fadeOut()
```

Comment: Hi Evan, Your assumption that the target element is indeed el is correct, however and unfortunately your code suggestion didn't work :(
Thanks for the reply nonetheless. :)

Comment: If I put YOUR code line instead of @remove() in the success callback, that's the correct answer!

Comment: fadeout shouldn't automatically remove the view or cleanup the events or anything. i would suspect that your @model.destroy method might be making the appropriate remove? or perhaps another method is getting triggered. i updated my answer to just have the fadeout there as you suggested

Comment: Yes, I understand now very clearly what's going on, the @model.destroy() call will delete the underlying record, however it's obvious we have to wait for the server to respond, hence the need to fadeOut() the $(@el) on the success callback. (apparently we can't remove the view and delete the model at the same time). Anyways, thanks for the enlightenment on this regard. :)

Answer (score 1):

fadeOut() has a success callback - I would suggest using that for your @remove() call:

```
removeMember: ->
  @model.destroy
    data:
      collective_id: gon.collective.id
    contentType: 'application/json'
    success: =>
      $(@el).fadeOut(100, @remove())
```

Comment: Pretty close! I don't know why, but actually this alone works: $(@el).fadeOut(2000) and I double checked it, it's doing its job because the record is being deleted from the DB.

Comment: I don't understand it though, maybe somewhere in the backbone docs it says that fadeOut will result in an Automatic call to remove(), because it seems to be the case. right? Hopefully somebody around here can explain it.